# Firebase: app_remove event counts : before or after first open?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

We are tracking app data with Firebase analytics. We are tracking first-open and app-remove on weekly basis. **Does Firebase "app_remove" counts the users only who first-open and removes the app ?** or It counts all app_removals after installation(regardless of the whether the user has opened the app or not?)